# Style the first child that hasn't got a class

Tags: css

With CSS is it possible to target the first child that hasn't got a class

```
<div class="parent">
  <p class="hidden">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p class="hidden">Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
</div>
```

So something like this ...

```
.parent p:not(.hidden):first-child {
  color:#ff0000
 }
```

The desired effect would be that paragraph 3 would now be red

Comment: `.hidden + p {}` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm assuming OP doesn't necessarily know the exact HTML, and would like a selector that would select the first `p` without a class. Additionally, your code selects paragraph 2 and 3.

Comment: @k97513 - Correct on both accounts

Comment: in this case, the answer is withinh the duplicate (the second duplicate do the opposite but the logic is the same)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - there is nothing in that question that achieves my goal - this is not a duplicated question ... you cannot use 'first-of-type' as suggested in that question to achieve my goal by reversing the logic as you suggest

Comment: the duplicate question will not show you how to achieve your goal it will give the details about how those selector works so you understand them and you think about another way to do  .. I have added another duplicate explaining the same